# How to get REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH request to return RefreshToken

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito to login users and save a `RefreshToken` so they don't have to type their password after the initial setup. I need to be able to login with the `RefreshToken` and get a new `RefreshToken` to save for next time. However, when I call `InitiateAuthAsync`, it does not return the `RefreshToken`.

C#:

```
var refreshReq = new InitiateAuthRequest();
refreshReq.ClientId = _clientId;

refreshReq.AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH;
refreshReq.AuthParameters.Add("SECRET_HASH", 
    SecretHash(_clientId, _clientSecret, username));
refreshReq.AuthParameters.Add("REFRESH_TOKEN", refreshToken);


var clientResp = cognitoProvider.InitiateAuthAsync(refreshReq).Result;
```

Response:

```
{
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "<accessToken>",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "IdToken": "<idToken>",
        "TokenType": "Bearer"
    },
    "ChallengeParameters": {}
}
```

And this is the response from the login with a working ResponseToken:

```
{
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "<accessToken>",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "IdToken": "<idToken>",
        "RefreshToken": "<refreshToken>",
        "TokenType": "Bearer"
    },
    "ChallengeParameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the AWS Cognito API. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) say that `InitiateAuth` should return an updated RefreshToken, but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the main question here there is an issues if one can't refresh the refresh token.
The best security practice is to regenerate a new Access Token and a new Refresh Token every X minutes. This way if a malicious 3rd party player get a hold on the Access Token / Refresh Token - they will be valid until the next cycle of refreshing the token by the application.
This is very weird that AWS are not supporting such mechanism that is commonly used in the web - such as Passport ID and authentication etc.

Answer (score 0):

The **refresh token** is only returned in the initial sign in and it can be used more than once to get a new **access token** and **id token**. Be aware of your user pool configuration because it will not work if you are using device tracking and the device use to sign in is not confirmed.

Comment: you can generate new tokens with the same refresh token for multiple times as long as the refresh token is not expired. But when you use REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH flow, only idToken and accessToken are generated. In this case, it is not possible to create an infinite refresh (a new refresh token every refresh token flow), maybe this is not a bug, but an AWS security implementation.

Comment: I think the same, that its not a bug. But its not in the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

The refresh token is a long-lived token and there's no point returning it as it's still valid for many days. If the default 30-day expiry time is not long enough you can increase it to up to 3650 days.

Comment: Of course there's a point in returning a new token! After 30 days (actually 28 because of February), my users had to re-enter their password, which they don't remember after a month. I hesitate to make this the answer, though, since the answer is that it's broken.

Comment: Saving the refresh token plus be able to use the same one over and over for a 30 days or more is a bad security practice. What if the refresh token is compromised? Then it can be used by a malicious 3rd party in order to get hold on the account.